# WP Background Processing - task() is not being executed through CRON Job

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, background-process, crm

I'm using [WP Background Processing](https://github.com/deliciousbrains/wp-background-processing) Library to get a large amount of properties (1000+) from the third-party CRM service and do specific actions. I need to keep the data in sync with the data stored in WordPress - both automatically (every 5-10 minutes) and manually (through a custom backend page).

The syncing process (between CRM and WordPress) includes the following actions:

- **create:** in case of new properties
- **update:** in case of property changes
- **delete:** in case of property deletion

The issue I face is that the important `task()` function (which is doing all the processes) is not being executed at all.

Since website speed is very important, I didn't include it in the functions.php file but created a separate php file (sync.php) and wrote the below code in it:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/bg-processing/vendor/deliciousbrains/wp-background-processing/classes/wp-async-request.php';
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/bg-processing/vendor/deliciousbrains/wp-background-processing/classes/wp-background-process.php';
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/class-property-sync-process.php';

$process = new CRM_Sync_Process();
$properties = get_properties_from_crm();
if($properties){
    foreach ( $properties as $property ) {
        $process->push_to_queue($property);
    }

    $process->save()->dispatch();
}else{
    global $wpdb;
    $ins_date = date('d M Y | g:i a');
    $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'sync_log', array('sync_text' => 'Pproperties are up to date.', 'ins_date' => $ins_date, 'date' => $current_date, 'datetime' => $datetime));
}
```

In the class-property-sync-process.php I have following code:

```
class CRM_Sync_Process extends WP_Background_Process {
    protected $action = 'sync_process';
    protected $prefix = 'prf';

    // THIS IS NOT EXECUTING
    protected function task( $item ) {
        $referenceID = $item['Id'];

        error_log('Property ID ' . $item['Id']);

        $existing_post = get_existing_post($item['Id']);
        if ( $existing_post ) {
            // Update the existing post
            update_post_with_crm_data( $item['Id'], $existing_post, $item );
        } else {
            // Create a new post
        }

        $this->complete_step();
        return false;
    }

    protected function complete() {
        parent::complete();
    }

}

function get_properties_from_crm() {
    // $response comes from CRM
    $properties = json_decode($response, true);
    if($properties){
        $propertiesList = $propertiesData;
    }else{
        // log in the DB
        $propertiesList = '';
    }

    return $propertiesList;
}

function get_existing_post($referenceID) {
    // Use the property ID to search for a matching post
    $args = array(
        // ...
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    if ( $posts ) {
        return $posts[0]->ID;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function update_post_with_crm_data( $referenceID, $post_id, $crm_data ) {
    // Update the post fields with the new information from the CRM
    // ...
    // Log the update in the system logs
    
    global $wpdb;
    $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $logText = 'Updated property '.$post_id.' with CRM new data.';
    $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . 'sync_log', array('sync_text' => $logText, 'date' => $current_date, 'datetime' => $datetime));
}
```

Lastly, I've disabled WP Cron (`define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)`) and created a cron job (at a server level) on the sync.php file to run the code every 5 minutes. In the options table, I can see the data stored in a serialized way, however, the task() function is not being executed, as I should have seen logs imported into the custom table I created, however, I don't see it working.

I will appreciate any ideas and thoughts on the issue I'm facing.